# Scala pattern matching type with inherited classes

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I have a series of inherited classes,with some more methods than the base class. Like this:

```
class Animal
{  
  var Name: String
}  
class Fish extends Animal
{  
  def swim()  
  {  
    println("I'm a Fish and i'm swimming!");  
  }
}
class Turtle extends Animal
{
  def swim()  
  {  
    println("I'm a Turtle and i'm swimming!");  
  }
}
```

I would like to use the type match pattern to a generic `Animal` class, to recognize the exact type and apply the `swim()` method if it can, like this:

```
myAnimal match {
  case m:Fish => m.Swim()
  case m:Turtle => m.Swim()
  case _: => doSomethingElse()
}
```

I would like to write it in an elegant way, avoiding to repeat continuously the lines.

I know that I can do this:

```
myAnimal match {
  case (_:Fish | _:Turtle) => println("I can do this!")
}
```

And I know, as I wrote above, that I can do:

```
myAnimal match {
  case m:Fish => m.swim()
}
```

but, I can't put them in or, like this

```
myAnimal match {
  case (m:Fish | m:Turtle) => m.swim() //ERROR (cannot recognize swim() method)

  //Not even this
  case m @ (_:Fish | _:Turtle) => m.swim() //ERROR (cannot recognize swim() method)
  case _: => doSomethingElse()
}
```

A good solution would be to insert an intermediate class, like `AnimalsThatCanSwim` that extend `Animals`. This solution should be the last option, because I have to avoid changing the extended classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use structural types combined with an extractor that uses reflection to check if your object has a `swim` method. Thanks to Mateusz Kubuszok and Dmytro Mitin, I now have a solution that seems to work.

Use like this:

```
myAnimal match {
  case CanSwim(m) => m.swim()
  case _          => println("Boohoo, I can't swim!")
}
```

The other stuff:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

type CanSwim = { def swim(): Unit }

object CanSwim {
  def unapply(arg: Any): Option[CanSwim] = {
    try {
      var res: Option[CanSwim] = None
      for (symb <- runtimeMirror(arg.getClass.getClassLoader)
             .reflect(arg)
             .symbol
             .info
             .member(TermName("swim"))  //get all methods named swim
             .asTerm
             .alternatives) { //alternatives because it might be overloaded
        if (symb.isMethod) {
          val msymb = symb.asMethod
          //Check if the signature matches (Returns Unit and has 1 empty parameter list)
          if (msymb.returnType =:= typeOf[Unit] && msymb.paramLists == List(List()))
            res = Some(arg.asInstanceOf[CanSwim])
        }
      }
      res
    } catch {
      case _ => None  
      //Might want to change this, but I don't think it's necessary to handle or throw exceptions
      //If it failed, it probably means it can't swim
    }
  }
}
```

Link to [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/83qpP1sbSBqZuRWFGfG0pw)

However, I really wouldn't recommend it. It's probably just easier to refactor your code.

```html
<script src="https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gFBe7jTQQiW3WnPVTJoFPw.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you try this pattern matching on something that is not `CanSwim` you'll get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`, it would be safer to run cast to structural type in some Try and use that logic to build a custom extractor.

Comment: @user now `swim` is executed twice.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yup, thanks for pointing that out, will try to fix